# How to install Python 3.6 IDLE, to work with Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda on Ubuntu 14.04. Anaconda installed Python3.6. I already had Python2.7 (Ubuntu default) and then Python3.4(I installed before Anaconda).

Although Anaconda have made importing packages much easier, I am not able to save codes in '.py' file. Anaconda has ipython (which looks like idle shell), jupyter (save in '.ipynb') but none offer to save it as scripts with '.py' extension. I want '.py' scripts which IDLE offered.

When I type in terminal

```
anand@anand-dell:~$ python
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 13 2017, 12:02:49) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

but when i click Idle it defaults to

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 28 2017, 16:41:13) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
```

How can i install python3.6 IDLE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download `idlelib` from cpython repo: https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit/#/home?url=https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.6/Lib/idlelib
2. Extract `idlelib` to `site-packages` of anaconda.
3. Create `/usr/local/bin/idle` with following content. (Remember to modify the first line to correct path of Anaconda python)

   ```
   #!/usr/local/lib/python3.6.2/bin/python3.6

   from idlelib.pyshell import main
   if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
   ```

Comment: Thank you Ping. I have now started using Spyder instead of IDLE and as it turns out it is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate conda environment first
If you haven't created any environment try below command

```
source activate base
```

After this you will be able to launch idle in anaconda using command

```
idle3
```

and to deactivate environment use

```
source deactivate
```

or

```
source deactivate base
```